# How to make "Backup & Migrate" not backup my Backups?

Tags: 8, migrations, backups

I am configuring a backup-automatism with Backup & Migrate to regularly save a copy of the site and my database on the server. The scheduling works quite well and every week a copy of the site is stored in my private directory.
Unfortunately it also stores my recent backups, so the size of each backup increases over time.
There is a field in the "Backup & Migrate" settings for that, but it seems to ignore all the input.

[image: exclude files directory in backup & migrate]

(Backups are all stored in the folder "backup_migrate" in the private-files directory)

Does anyone have a solution for my issue?

Comment: Isn't it a bit counterproductive to backup your files into the same location you're generating the backup from? How will you recover if the files are deleted?

Comment: yeah sure, I would definately choose an option to backup my files to a remote destination, but this functionality hasn't been ported yet. Any other recommendations?

Comment: What is a proper way in automating backups in D8?